# Constant propagation in llvm

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

I was checking llvm's constant propagation pass [-sccp](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#id92), with the following program

```
int a,b,c;
a=1;
b=2;
c=a+b;
```

I was expecting an output

```
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %c = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %b, align 4
  store i32 3, i32* %c, align 4 //constant propagation
```

But I am getting the following output

```
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %c = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %b, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1 //no constant propagation
  store i32 %add, i32* %c, align 4
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any passes in llvm to achieve this constant propagation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant propagation pass, like many other passes, assumes [mem2reg](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register) has been used on the code first.

Comment: Oak got it thanks.
But is there a case in which sccp will fail to detect a constant.

Comment: @RakeshNair I'm sure there are cases - you just demonstrated it doesn't look through stores and loads - but I believe that in practice it's rare for it to fail.